# Change Base class at runtime java

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance

Hello I have a an `Activity` (`class`) that i want to enable NFC feature for it when the `android` API level is 14 and up . and i dont want to enable it below. now the `Activity` is 1000 lines and to use `NFC` i have to extend a `class` in a `jar` file . so what should i do ??? i cant use `aggregation` for the NFC !! and i dont want to make 2 `Activities` and copy past the same code to them and make one of them extends NFC . any work around , sorry if you want more clarification post a comment . I am not an `OOP` super star.

**Edit**

[image]

What i want to be able to do is on android API level 14 to make the VideoActivity to extends NFC custom class . because the NFC custom class continas api's that is available on android API level 14

and when the API level is below 14 i want the VideoActivity to extends Activity class .

[image]

Note: the NFC custom class exist in a jar (library jar).

Comment: Which class do you have to extend, and why?

Comment: I have a class called VideoActivity , what i want on android API level 14 and up i want the VideoActivity to extends NFC class in the jar to enable NFC and if the android API level below android API level 14 i dont want to extend the NFC class

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, really. Where is this NFC class coming from? Do you really need it to be the same activity, or could it be a new activity which calls into your existing one?

Comment: @user4o01 Android does not require you to inherit from a special class to utilize NFC. You can do it from a normal Activity.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question but, if you want to enable NFC only for certain API level why don't you do version checking using if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH).

Comment: You just keep saying the same thing again and again - you keep saying that you *have* to use inheritance rather than composition, but you've given no *reasons* for it. Sorry, I don't think I'm going to be able to help you.

Comment: the NFC class is an Activity and exist in a jar file thats why.

Comment: So why not use NFC always when available? I've put some finished activities on http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/ you might dig into.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do.. and if I'm wrong and it possible so I think its a bad idea (design and implementation) to change the extended class at runtime.. 
check for the api level and if it below 14 -> show message that it's not supported on the device..